# Yet another "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NA' to data type int."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

CTEI have a query that runs a table valued function that I reuse it cross joining to another table. It was working fine in both cases until I decided to add 2 new parameters to the function. The first case works fine however the second case it does not work and I get this "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NA' to data type int." What is causing this to happen?

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Char4X, Y FROM TableA WHERE Char4X = '2.01'
)
SELECT f.*, a.* 
FROM dbo.UDF_Function1('2014-03-01', '2015-03-01', NULL, 'ABCDE', NULL, NULL) f
CROSS JOIN CTE a
```

Whether I use a CTE or not it is the same error. There is no 'NA' value in any table in any column in my database well I do know there is a lot of layers to the function as in views and filtering going on so I am not 100% sure if I need to concentrate my focus here. Anyhow the underlining function does no conversion or casting to INT. The function runs fine by itself without the cross join. The first 2 parameters are datetime and the rest are all varchar and allow nulls.

Comment: Does the query in the CTE run by itself?

Comment: As I said I originally had it working without the CTE (makes no difference) and my last change I added 2 more varchar parameters to my function and now is decided not to work. The CTE is just me experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok who is the dummy? Me of course. For what it is worth in case somebody else has the same problem "never assume". I ran the following query to see if there were any columns containing 'NA' and low and behold I found some. I narrowed my issued down to one of the views that was used in the query I had in the function and inside the view was a CAST! And because one of the values was 'NA' my function un-deterministically failed:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE cursorX CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.name As [TABLE], c.name AS [COLUMN]--, system_type_id
FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE t.name <> 'sysdiagrams'
  AND c.system_type_id NOT IN (42, 56, 108)
ORDER BY t.name, c.system_type_id

DECLARE @T sysname, @C sysname

OPEN cursorX

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorX INTO @T, @C

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = N'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + @T + ' WHERE ' + @C + ' = ''NA'')
BEGIN
    PRINT ''Table=' + @T + ', Column=' + @C + '''
    SELECT * FROM ' + @T + ' WHERE ' + @C + ' = ''NA''
END'
    --PRINT (@sql)
    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorX INTO @T, @C
END

CLOSE cursorX
DEALLOCATE cursor
```